# Python Global List Issue

Tags: python, global

I am facing issue in my code.My global list is getting updated though I have not updating it.My list "tempList2"which is getting updated.
 My aim is to get 1 value at a time from "tagValueList1" appending it "tempList2"
and append it in list of 5 elements.Keeping other values 0.For example
 I am getting first value as 2.0 in "tempList2" so the list "FinalValues1" will be [2.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0].In second loop if I am getting values in "tempList2" as [2.0,3.0] then FinalValues1" will be [2.0,3.0,0.0,0.0,0.0] and so on.

My code is

```
tagValueList1 = []
tempList1 = []
tempListValues = []
tempList2 = []
def PassData():
    global message
    global tagValueList1
    global tempListValues
    global tempList1
    global tempList2
    tempListVar=1
    tempList2=[]
    #print("tagValueList1....",tagValueList1)
    tagValueList1 = [1,2,3,4,5]
    for j in tagValueList1:
        if tagValueList1 !=[]:
        tempListValues.append(tagValueList1[j])
    if tagValueList1 !=[]: 
        if len(tempList2)<=50:
            tempListVar = float(tagValueList1[j])
            tempList2.append(tempListVar)
            print("tempList2 Func1 ", tempList2)
    drawChart()
def drawChart():
    global tempList2
    xyz= [1.1, 1.2, 1.3]
    TempValues1 = tempList2
    FinalValues1 = []
    FinalValues1 = TempValues1
    LenList=len(TempValues1)
    LenList1=0
    print("tempList2 length bfore loop", len(tempList2))
    if TempValues1 != []:
        if LenList<=50:
            LenList1 = 50 - LenList

    tempLEN1 = LenList1
    if tagValueList1 !=[]: 
        for i in range(0, 5):
            FinalValues1.append(float(0.0))
            #print(" FinalValues1  ....",FinalValues1)
            print("tempList2 Func2....",len(tempList2))

PassData()
```

Output I am getting as

```
tempList2 Func1  [2.0]
tempList2 length bfore loop 1
tempList2 Func2.... 2
tempList2 Func2.... 3
tempList2 Func2.... 4
tempList2 Func2.... 5
tempList2 Func2.... 6
tempList2 Func1  [2.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 3.0]
tempList2 length bfore loop 7
tempList2 Func2.... 8
tempList2 Func2.... 9
tempList2 Func2.... 10
tempList2 Func2.... 11
tempList2 Func2.... 12
tempList2 Func1  [2.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 3.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 
4.0]
tempList2 length bfore loop 13
tempList2 Func2.... 14
tempList2 Func2.... 15
tempList2 Func2.... 16
tempList2 Func2.... 17
tempList2 Func2.... 18
tempList2 Func1  [2.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 3.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 
4.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 5.0]
tempList2 length bfore loop 19
tempList2 Func2.... 20
tempList2 Func2.... 21
tempList2 Func2.... 22
tempList2 Func2.... 23
tempList2 Func2.... 24
```

Comment: Don't use globals. Rewrite using function parameters and return values

Comment: Actually I am new to python .I have edited the code as suggested by you but getting same result.

Comment: You are assigning the `global templist2` to additional identifiers and then changing the list through those identifiers. `TempValues1 = tempList2` ... `FinalValues1 = TempValues1` ... `FinalValues1.append(float(0.0))` this will change the underlying list that all these identifiers are pointing to. Perhaps you need a copy of the list, e.g.  `TempValues1 = list(tempList2)`

Comment: Thank you so much @AChampion .It worked.Great Help.